# Reconciling two interpretations of electrical energy transfer

Tags: energy, electricity, electric-circuits, electric-fields, charge

Currently, there are two seemingly different ways of thinking about what causes charge-carrying electrons to "move" in a wire.

We are told the following:

1) The electric field exerts a force on the charge carriers in a wire. The field accelerates the charge and is responsible for its movement.

2) An electron is impelled to move by the neighboring electrons that precede it, causing it to interact with the neighbors that follow. It is in this wavelike fashion that energy is transferred at high fractions of the speed of light.

This paints a fuzzy picture in my mind when trying to reason about the physical circumstances of an individual electron.

On the one hand, you, the electron, have the field exerting a force on you, accelerating you in its direction.

On the other hand, the field is paid no mention, and you are merely transferring the energy imparted to you by neighboring electrons, to neighboring electrons.

My guess is that the reality is some mixture of these two interpretations. The electrons must be accelerated by the field, but they must also fall subject to the interactions with neighboring electrons. I just don't quite know how to combine these when thinking about the transfer of energy through the wire.

Comment: How do you think electron interact. except through electric fields?

Answer (score -1):

The electric field accelerates the electron for sure. Doesn't mean that the electron moves all over. It vibrates causing a change in the potential energy(electromagnetic) in the neighbourhood and the effect is observed through out the conductor.

Comment: Why don't you think the electrons in a conductor move? They most assuredly do.

Comment: "move all over"?